# Quadratic optimisation problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization, finance

I'm trying to solve the optimisation problem $\mathbf x^\top\mathbf A\mathbf x$ such that $x_1 + \ldots + x_n = 1$, where $\mathbf x$ is the vector of variables to be optimised and $\mathbf A$ is some arbitrary matrix.

This is of course easy to do when $x$ is of small dimension using

```
Minimize[{f, cons}, {x1, x2, ...}]
```

But when $\mathbf x$ is arbitrarily large, this does not scale up in an obvious way. I was looking for some sort of built-in quadratic optimiser similar to [`quadprog` in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html), but there does not seem to be such a thing.

Comment: If your $A$ is allowed to be indefinite, you will find nothing, since $f=x^TAx$ is then unbounded. Is your $A$ positive definite?

Comment: If your $A$ is definite, then try first a direct forumlation: `n = 5;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
A = Transpose@A.A;
Eigenvalues@A
x = Array[xc, n];
f = x.A.x;
cons = Total@x == 1;
NMinimize[{f, cons}, x]`

Comment: Or maybe `#/Total[#] &@LinearSolve[A + Transpose@A, Table[1, {Length@A}]]`.

Comment: (1) A specific  example would be useful here. (2) `FindMinimum` supports `Method -> "QuadraticProgramming"`.

Comment: @Daniel, that's the one that uses CLP under the hood, no?

Comment: @J.M. If it uses CLP under the hood (which it does), is the correct response to your wording "no", or "yes"? (And sorry for answering a question with a question.)

Comment: @Daniel, OK, at least my memory did not fail me this time... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, the matrix $\mathbf A$ should be symmetric positive definite for the minimization of $\mathbf x^\top\mathbf A\mathbf x$ to make sense. With that, here's an example of how to get a minimal vector corresponding to an SPD matrix of arbitrary dimensions:

```
With[{n = 8},
     mat = HilbertMatrix[n];
     Minimize[{x.mat.x, x.ConstantArray[1, n] == 1}, x ∈ FullRegion[n]]]
   {1/64, {x -> {-1/8, 63/8, -945/8, 5775/8, -17325/8, 27027/8, -21021/8, 6435/8}}}
```

Check that the constraint is satisfied:

```
Total[x /. Last[%]]
   1
```

(Note that this still works if `Minimize[]` is replaced with `NMinimize[]`.)